# Display related data in Details action MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have two tables (one to many relationship) and I want to display related data from second table in Details View. Models for tables:

```
     public partial class jprl_uplny
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string IDPS { get; set; }

    public string DC { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255)]
    public string CP { get; set; }

    public double? PS { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<etaze> Etaze { get; set; }

}}

public partial class etaze
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string IDPS { get; set; }

    public double? ET { get; set; }

    public double? VEK { get; set; }

    public double? VYM { get; set; }
}
```

In table "etaze" , IDPS column is foreign key for table "jprl_uplny", too.

Model "Model1" defines my dbContext

```
    public partial class Model1 : DbContext
{
    public Model1()
        : base("name=Model1")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<jprl_uplny> jprl_uplny { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<etaze> Etaze { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    }
}
```

After scaffolding, ActionResult Details in my controller looks like:

```
public ActionResult Details(string id)
    {

        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        jprl_uplny jprl_uplny = db.jprl_uplny.Find(id);
        if (jprl_uplny == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(jprl_uplny);
    }
```

When I click on "details" for some row in table which display´s values from "jprl_uplny" (index.cshtml), I want to display related data from "etaze" (in details.cshtml). 
Can someone advise me how to relate "jprl_uplny" and "etaze" with IDPS column in my Controller in Actionresult Details (one to many relationship)?

Comment: What do you mean _and foreign key for table "jprl_uplny", too_? How could it be the FK as well if its a one-to-many?

Comment: I apologize it´s my mistake. Table "etaze" has composite primary key (IDPS + ET) and FK is IDPS. @StephenMuecke

Comment: You can always do `jprl_uplny.Etaze = db.etaz.Where(x => x.IDPS == id);`

Comment: I added it to my actionresult. Can you also advise me how I can display data from "etaze" in Details View ? Now in this View i have `@model mvc.Models.jprl_uplny` and when I display data from "jprl_uplny" - `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PS)` . It was generated after scaffolding @StephenMuecke

Comment: `@foreach(var etaze in Model.Etaze) { @Html.DisplayFor(m => etaze.ET) ..... }`